# How to draw guide lines spanning between two panels or graphs?

Tags: plotting

[image]

I would like to draw the blue guide lines as shown spanning between the top and bottom graphs. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add any germane code to generate the graphs and clarify precisely how these "guide lines" are defined.

Comment: Kuba answered. (Graph is generated in xmgrace and not mathematica.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is `PlotRangeClipping-> False`:

```
With[{stdopt = 
   Sequence[Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
            PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]},
 Column[{
   Plot[x, {x, 0, Pi/2}, Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Line[{{.5, .5}, {.5, -1}}]}, stdopt],
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, stdopt, Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Line[{{0, Sin@.5}, 
                                                 {.5, Sin@.5}, {.5, 5}}]}]
   }, Spacings -> 0]]
```

> [image]

Comment: You may be also interested in `PlotRangePadding->0`.

Comment: It's the Epilog which did the trick. Very nice!